# C++ ¿Como puedo analizar todo el contenido de un Array en un solo codigo?

Tags: c++

Estoy empezando con este lenguaje y no encuentro por ningún lado como revisar los datos de un array. Como pueden ver en mi código quiero que el if analice la variable selección y la compare con los datos que hay dentro del array nombres[] pero no encuentro la manera de hacer esto.

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string nombres[3] = {"alejandro","jose","juan"};
    string seleccion;

    cout<<"Ingrese su nombre ";cin>>seleccion;

    if (seleccion==nombres[]){
        cout<<"Bienvenido";
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Error";  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer para verificar valores en un array es **recorrerlo** y hacer la verificación uno por uno. Para recorrerlo en este caso puede usar un **for** o un **while**.

Te doy el ejemplo con un for

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  string nombres[3] = {"alejandro","jose","juan"};
  string seleccion;

  cout<<"Ingrese su nombre "; cin>>seleccion;

  bool encontrado = false;
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    if (seleccion==nombres[i]){
      cout<<"Bienvenido";
      encontrado = true;
    }
  }
  if(!encontrado) {
    cout<<"Error";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

El for tiene 3 partes: la inicializacion `int i=0`, la condición `i<3` y una actualización `i++` que es similar a escribir `i=i+1`. Esto hara que el código que esta dentro se ejecute 3 veces(es decir se ejecutarán 3 if, uno para cada valor del array nombres).

Dentro del `if` lo unico que cambia es `nombres[i]`, haciendo uso del `[i]` accedemos a cada uno de los valores del array.

Puede encontrar mas informacion en la documentacion de c++ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for o en varios tutoriales por internet

Answer (score 3):

En tú caso, una **lista ordenada**, use [binary_search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/) de `#include<algorithm>`:

```
binary_search(begin(nombres), end(nombres), seleccion)
```

Para listas no ordenadas, use [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/).

Comment: Ojo, puede que no todas las listas sean compatibles con `binary_search`, para que lo sean, sus iteradores deben ser [*forward iterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator).

Answer (score 3):

Decir que necesitas "*revisar los datos de un array*" es muy vago y ambiguo. Por lo que muestras en tu código podemos deducir que lo que quieres es buscar un dato dentro de una formación<sup>1</sup>, podrías hacerlo recorriendo los elementos y comparando con el dato:

```
string nombres[3] = {"alejandro","jose","juan"};
string seleccion;
bool encontrado = falso;

cout<<"Ingrese su nombre ";cin>>seleccion;

for (const auto &nombre : nombres)
{
    if ((encontrado = (nombre == seleccion)))
        break;
}

if (encontrado)
{
    cout << "Bienvenido\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "Error\n";
}
```

A grandes rasgos, eso mismo es lo que hace la función [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) de la cabecera [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm):

```
string nombres[3] = {"alejandro","jose","juan"};
string seleccion;

cout<<"Ingrese su nombre ";cin>>seleccion;
bool encontrado = find(begin(nombres), end(nombres), seleccion) != end(nombres);

if (encontrado)
{
    cout << "Bienvenido\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "Error\n";
}
```

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.